# Tkinter - Resizing window, without getting the dimensions of frames/widgets changed

Tags: python, tkinter

I created the graphics for a Tkinter app.

This is how it looks
[image]

It looks ok, but it is very large in the Y axis. I would like the window to be cut, a bit below the last frame.

So i went to do this by changing the HEIGHT variable, that is passed to my canvas. (700 -> 200)

Unfortunately, some frames and widgets are resized and this doe not look good.

Here you can see the outcome.

[image]

Asyou can see the Y axis is still large, but the widgets are so small.

Is there a way to just "cut" the window right below the last frame? With no resizes?

Here is my full code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import serial.tools.list_ports


#to be used on our canvas
HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH = 800

# --- functions ---
def serial_ports():    
    return serial.tools.list_ports.comports()

def on_select(event=None):

    # get selection from event    
    print("event.widget:", event.widget.get())

    # or get selection directly from combobox
    print("comboboxes: ", cb.get())

def single_Sensor():    
    clicked_new = int(clicked)
# --- functions ---



# --- main ---
root = tk.Tk() #here we create our tkinter window
root.title("Sensor Interface")

#we use canvas as a placeholder, to get our initial screen size (we have defined HEIGHT and WIDTH)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

#we use frames to organize all the widgets in the screen

# --- frame 1 ---
frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.place(relx=0, rely=0.05, relheight=0.03, relwidth=1, anchor='nw') #we use relheight and relwidth to fill whatever the parent is - in this case- root

label0 = tk.Label(frame1, text="Select the COM port that the device is plugged in: ")
label0.config(font=("TkDefaultFont", 8))
label0.place(relx = 0.1, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.5)


cb = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=serial_ports())
cb.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
# assign function to combobox
cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', on_select)
# --- frame 1 ---



# --- frame 2 ---
frame2 = tk.Frame(root, bd=5) #REMOVED THIS bg='#80c1ff' (i used it to see the borders of the frame)
frame2.place(relx=0, rely=0.1, relheight=0.07, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')

#button
button = tk.Button(frame2, text="Measure all Sensors", bg='#80c1ff', fg='red')  #bg='gray'
button.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.5, anchor='center')

#label
label1 = tk.Label(frame2, text="OR, select a single sensor to measure: ")
label1.config(font=("TkDefaultFont", 9))
label1.place(relx = 0.32, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.4)

#dropdown
OPTIONS = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
clicked = tk.StringVar()
clicked.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default value
drop = tk.OptionMenu(frame2, clicked, *OPTIONS)
drop.place(relx = 0.65, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.08, relheight=0.6)

dropDownButton = tk.Button(frame2, text="Measure this sensor", bg='#80c1ff', fg='red', command=single_Sensor) #bg='gray'
dropDownButton.place(relx = 0.85, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
# --- frame 2 ---



# --- frame 3 ---
frame3 = tk.Frame(root, bd=5) #REMOVED THIS bg='#80c1ff' (i used it to see the borders of the frame)
frame3.place(relx=0, rely=0.2, relheight=0.07, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')

stop_button = tk.Button(frame3, text="STOP measurement(s)", bg='#80c1ff', fg='red')
stop_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
# --- frame 3 ---



# --- frame 4 ---
frame4 = tk.Frame(root, bd=5)
frame4.place(relx=0, rely=0.3, relheight=0.09, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')

label2 = tk.Label(frame4, text="Select a sensor to plot data: ")
label2.place(relx = 0.1, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.5)

clickedForPlotting = tk.StringVar()
clickedForPlotting.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default value
dropPlot = tk.OptionMenu(frame4, clickedForPlotting, *OPTIONS)
dropPlot.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')

dropDownButton = tk.Button(frame4, text="Plot sensor data", bg='#80c1ff', fg='red', command=single_Sensor) #bg='gray'
dropDownButton.place(relx = 0.85, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
# --- frame 4 ---


root.mainloop() #here we run our app
# --- main ---
```

Comment: The best solution is to strip out all calls to `place`, and use `grid` or `pack`.

Comment: Thanks but its my first time that i do tkinter, and because i am in a hurry and i do not want to waste time on the GUI,  i will just leave place(). However, i read in many places taht place() is the worst of the three. Thanks for the input!

Comment: `pack` and `grid` likely would have been quicker. `place` requires that you spend a lot of time fiddling with coordinates and dimensions. <shrug>

Comment: Will it take a lot of time to refactor my code? Of pack() and grid(), what do you think it's the fastest to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can change canvas size but for the widgets, change the rely=0.3 ! you see it's y position is Relative! to the frame hehe...like if the height is 100, then its y is 30. The ratio is equal no matter the height.

Comment: Thanks! I should do this for all frames? Is there a value that you think it will work better?

Comment: yes, well it is a trial and error thing, you could even go without the frames and use the widgets themselves... one can also use .pack() instead, it's easier Imo, if you are just doing like rows of widgets